# LinkedBlockingQueue in java jdk 1.7

Tags: java, concurrency

I read LinkedBlockingQueue source code in JDK1.7 and can't understand the method.

```
public boolean offer(E e) {
    if (e == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    final AtomicInteger count = this.count;
    if (count.get() == capacity)
        return false;
    int c = -1;
    Node<E> node = new Node(e);
    final ReentrantLock putLock = this.putLock;
    putLock.lock();
    try {
        if (count.get() < capacity) {
            enqueue(node);
            c = count.getAndIncrement();
            if (c + 1 < capacity)
                notFull.signal();
        }
    } finally {
        putLock.unlock();
    }
    if (c == 0)
        signalNotEmpty();
    return c >= 0;
}
```

I don't know how this works.

```
 if (c == 0)
        signalNotEmpty();
```

if c == 0, means the queue is empty, so I think the method should be

```
signalEmpty();
```

Is there anyone could enlighten me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c` is initialized with

```
c = count.getAndIncrement();
```

So its value if the size of the queue **before** inserting the new node. So if the size before inserting the new node was 0, signalNotEmpty() is called to signal that the queue went from *empty* to *not empty*.